# pgBadger - generated report is empty but postgres log has events

Tags: postgresql

I've got problem with postgresql vs. pgBadger.

HTML reports wich were generated by pgBadger are empty (0 queries, 0 events, nothing about postgres work). But postgres log isnt' empty. There are events, etc.

I've tried many combinations with parameteres in postgresql.conf, (*eg. log_destination = syslog, with logging_collector = off, log_line_prefix - more or less values*),  and still the same.

At present, that parameteres was set in *postgresql.conf*:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'

logging_collector = on

log_directory = 'pg_log' 
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'

client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = notice 
log_min_error_statement = error

log_min_duration_statement = 0

log_checkpoints = on
log_connections = on
log_duration = off
log_line_prefix = '%t [%r] [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,e=%e '
log_statement = 'all'

lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

That's how I'm trying to use pgBadger and what I get in result:

```
#pgbadger -p -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log/postgresql-2014-10-15_125036.log -f stderr -o /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log/report.html
```

or

```
#pgbadger -p -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log -f stderr -o /var/log/postgresql/log_report.html
```

and the result is always the same:

```
/usr/src/pgbadger-6.2# pgbadger -p -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log/postgresql-2014-10-15_125036.log -f stderr -o /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log/report.html
[========================>] Parsed 12999 bytes of 12999 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
```

I work with: Debian 7, postgresql 9.3, pgbadger-6.2

Has anyone got similar problem with it?

Comment: I suggest using pg_stat_statements instead of pgbadger, personally.

Comment: Same problem here. How did you solve it?

Comment: Did anyone solve this? I'm trying to parse a csv file and I get the same thing, tried with -v option and nothing.. | The log_line_prefix isn't set up on the postgresql.conf, should it be set up?

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the `log_line_prefix` in `postgresql.conf` is as:

```
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] db=%d,user=%u '
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually i have got same problem. Can you follow this doc and fix your problem. Thanks

http://www.antelink.com/blog/using-pgbadger-monitor-your-postgresql-activity.html

I think you need to change log_statement to 'none'. then it may be resolve your problem.

You should use -v option to verbose mode.

pgbadger -f stderr -v /Data-directory/postgresql-Sat.log -o /Data-directory/postgresql-reports.html

Please change data directory as per your PostgreSQL cluster data

Comment: Please add some description about solution along with external link.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the `log_line_prefix` found in your `postgresql.conf` as `--prefix` flag to pgbadger. For AWS RDS, goto your RDS' `paramter group`, `log_line_prefix` parameter, to retrieve the same.

It's recommended to run your pgbadger in verbose mode to know what fails, as in,

`pgbadger -v --prefix='<<Your log_line_prefix>>:' <<logFileName>>`

For Ex:

1. **Assuming default format - NON VERBOSE**

   ```
   $ pgbadger pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   [========================>] Parsed 131114431 bytes of 413111431 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
   LOG: Ok, generating html report...
   ```

   As you can see, you can't see why queries and events are 0, even though you have data in your log file.
2. **Assuming default format - VERBOSE MODE**

   ```
   $ pgbadger -v pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Output 'html' reports will be written to out.html
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: pgBadger will use log format stderr to parse pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt.
   DEBUG: Starting to parse log file: pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Starting reading file pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt...
   DEBUG: Start parsing at offset 0 of file pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt to 413111431
   DEBUG: Unknown line format: 2018-07-15 16:00:07 UTC:192-198-10-132.local(23421):postgres@def_db:[12642]:LOG:  duration: 2772.244 ms  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM device_table WHERE date >= '2018-06-15'
   DEBUG: Unknown line format: 2018-07-15 16:00:07 UTC:192-198-10-132.local(23421):postgres@def_db:[45279]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '251'
   ...
   DEBUG: Unknown line format: 2018-07-18 16:59:56 UTC:192-198-10-132.local(23421):postgres@def_db:[54342]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '21'
   [========================>] Parsed 131114431 bytes of 413111431 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
   DEBUG: the log statistics gathering took:16 wallclock secs ( 3.99 usr +  2.03 sys =  6.02 CPU)
   LOG: Ok, generating html report...
   DEBUG: building reports took:  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.03 CPU)
   DEBUG: the total execution time took: 16 wallclock secs ( 4.00 usr +  2.05 sys =  6.05 CPU)
   ```
3. **Providing format - VERBOSE MODE**

   ```
   $ pgbadger -v --prefix='%t:%r:%u@%d:[%p]:' pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt 
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Output 'html' reports will be written to out.html
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Autodetected log format 'stderr' from pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: pgBadger will use log format stderr to parse pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt.
   DEBUG: Starting to parse log file: pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt
   DEBUG: Starting reading file pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt...
   DEBUG: Start parsing at offset 0 of file pgsql_log_Jul2018.txt to 413111431
   [========================>] Parsed 131114431 bytes of 413111431 (100.00%), queries: 55645, events: 34
   DEBUG: the log statistics gathering took:51 wallclock secs (48.81 usr +  0.84 sys = 49.65 CPU)
   LOG: Ok, generating html report...
   DEBUG: building reports took: 14 wallclock secs (13.22 usr +  0.18 sys = 13.40 CPU)
   DEBUG: the total execution time took: 65 wallclock secs (62.03 usr +  1.02 sys = 63.05 CPU)
   ```

In your case, since your `postgresql.conf` has

```
...
log_duration = off
log_line_prefix = '%t [%r] [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,e=%e '
log_statement = 'all'
...
```

Try using `--prefix='%t [%r] [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,e=%e '`

Also, Please check this [comment](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger/issues/132#issuecomment-34550223) from the pgbadger team - people usually get confused between `format` and `prefix`, hence referring the man page is a mandate and helpful.

Comment: pgbadger repo has moved. Use https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/issues/132#issuecomment-34550223